# PHP's XPath returns too many elements

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to use XPath in PHP and I get too many elements. This is my code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->strictErrorChecking = false;
$document->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DomXPath($document);
$placeholders = $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@class, "waf-ph-")]');
print '$placeholders->length: ' . $placeholders->length;
```

There is only ONE element that matches the query. One. Not a single one more. But here's my output:

```
$placeholders->length: 7
```

I'm using loadHTML because I won't have full control over the input when I'm done coding and I can't guarantee standards-compliant XHTML. I do intend to use Tidy, but I'm trying not to rely on it yet. But there is only ONE div that matches the XPath.

Further investigation seems to indicate that it is the same element that has been found seven times.

What's going on?

Edit: the source of the DOM file is an HTML file that somewhere contains the following (this is a dummy address):

```
<div class="waf-ph-https\:\/\/aserver\.com\/apath\/app\.php5">
  <p class="notification">This is to be substituted.</p>
</div>
```

The string "waf-ph-" is found nowhere else in the file.

Edit:

Trying the following:

```
foreach ($document->placeholders as $node) print $document->saveXML($node);
```

returns the text of the above DIV seven times.

Comment: Can you post a short piece of the XML that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Is this "same element" found at 7 different places in the XML document?

Comment: And what are the other 7 results that it found that "shouldn't be"?

Comment: It's the same DIV that's found 7 times, with the same class name.

Comment: Well, either the DIV is in the document seven times or the document is screwed. Output it completely with saveXML to see how DOM parsed it.

Comment: Try: `foreach ($placeholders as $node){echo spl_object_hash($node) . ', ';}`  That will tell you if it's the same object node multiple times, or just a similar one...

Comment: Outputting it completely, now with Tidy but with saveXML: another simple thing I should have thought of. I'll do it now. I've been fighting with this document since yesterday morning. If I fail, I'll have to parse HTML with RegExes. Nobody wants that. (Actually, most people at my office do want that; I'm trying to prove that using the DOM is the right thing.)

Comment: @ircmaxel I didn't know that command. I'll try that too. Thanks.

Comment: Well, basically it just returns an object identifier (used to check if two objects are the exact same instance)...

Comment: @ircmaxel It's the same one seven times.

Comment: @eje before you go down the road to madness with Regex, ask your folks why the HTML is broken in the first place and consider using a non-DOM based parser, e.g. XMLReader or the third-party SimpleHtmlDom.

Comment: @ircmaxel But that means I can reliably dump duplicates! It's what I need! (Not elegant, but it's really okay for my needs.) Could you put that as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Comment: Mark what as the right one?  Put what as the answer?  I'm confused (All I did was show you how to debug it, I didn't answer anything)...  Put your solution in an answer...

Comment: @Gordon The RegEx works and was already coded when I arrived. It does not raise PHP errors. I need to really wow the people work for with the DOM to make sure they will agree to use it. I'll look into XMLReader and SimpleHtmlDom for Monday. Now, it's past 7 PM and I'm the last one here and I have a two hour commute to get home. But I'll read up on them as soon as I am home. (Without my code, alas.)

Comment: @eje211: Wow! If any XPath 1.0 expression gets evaluate to a node set with duplicated nodes (just wrong by node set definition), then your xpath engine is broken.

Comment: Show us what `$text` contains; without going through tidy nor domdocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ircmxaell's comment about using `spl_object_hash()` really solved my problem and showed that, for once, the compiler (or interpreter) really was at fault. He should get credit for this question. Short of that, I'm writing this answer to credit him.

Comment: So how did you actually fix it? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: This was eight years ago, but I used the function above to determine with certainty if some unique nodes were returned multiple times and I only kept one copy of each. I don't remember how I did it then but now I'd probably do it with a set if the order is not important.

Comment: FYI spl_object_hash was returning the same value for the duplicates in my case but I have since determined that the issue was that I had forgotten to start my xpath expression with "." so it returned global results instead of results relative to the context node. So I wouldn't trust that function to debug such cases. Though hashing the xml helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I use the snippet you give, I get one result.

For this XML:

```
$text = <<< XML
<root>
    <div class="waf-ph-1"></div>
    <div class="waf-ph-2"></div>
    <div class="waf-ph-3"></div>
    <div class="waf-ph-4"></div>
</root>
XML;
```

you will get four matches for the given XPath.

For this XML:

```
$text = <<< XML
<root>
    <div class="waf-ph-1"></div>
    <div class="wbf-ph-2"></div>
    <div class="wcf-ph-3"></div>
    <div class="wdf-ph-4"></div>
</root>
XML;
```

you will get only one. Your code is correct. This must be your HTML. Also note that `//div` will match any `<div>` regardless of it's position in the document. The following XML will also return 4 found nodes for your code:

```
$text = <<< XML
<root>
    <div class="waf-ph-1">
        <div class="waf-ph-2">
            <div class="waf-ph-3">
                <div class="waf-ph-4">
    </div></div></div></div>
</root>
XML;
```

Comment: What you describe is exactly what my code was supposed to find. Thank you for telling me that my code is correct. I was going nuts! I'm not sure what's wrong then. ("It's never the compiler. Well, almost never.") It is going through Tidy... I'll look is Tidy duplicates my div. Though I don't see why it would. It's very hard and long for me to change the HTML file I source to the XPath: it's on restricted part of the server, so I just took for granted my code was wrong somehow. I guess I'll look into Tidy then. Even if the HTML is converted to XML, it's not likely to be THAT far off, is is?

Comment: @eje211 @ircmaxell gave a great suggestion in the comments below your question: output the found nodes. Do `foreach($placeholders as $node) { echo $document->saveXml($node); }` to print the XML to see what it found. Or simply output the whole document to see what DOM made of it.

Comment: I didn't think of doing a saveXML. I was thinking of print_r, that's not very useful. My bad. I'll do it right now.